# What would happen if a duelist didn't follow the instruction on the card?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

For example, when an opponent used a [Spell card: Card Destruction](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Destruction), the instruction on that spell card says:

> Each player discards their entire hand, then draws the same number of cards they discarded.

What would happen to the duelist if they didn't follow the instruction of that card? Would they get disqualified for that, or else?

Comment: If you're not playing a game by the rules, then the game is invalid. If it's just a tournament game then presumably they'd be disqualified (and their opponent would win by default). If it was a Shadow Game, who knows (and who would be stupid enough to try)?

Comment: In Arc-V episode 2 (I think), Yuya tries to pendulum summon with the wrong cards active and his duel disk flags an error. The duel disks seem to know how each card is supposed to be played, but I cannot recall a time from the series when characters deliberately stall to stop a card's effect from being played out.

Answer (score 1):

The duel disk contains an advance A.I. that is programmed to imply the rules of the game and figure out the rulings of the cards. During the battle city tournament, Joey wanted to summon Giltia the D. Knight, however it didn't appear on the field because it was a level 5 monster and Joey didn't tribute a monsters to summon it. Meaning that unless the conditions are not met, the A.I. will prevent certain cards from being played. This is the earliest example of the duel disk preventing players from making mistakes with their cards during a game.

I hope that my answer was helpful and fun to read. :)